# While using an if statement: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach, swiftui-button

I am trying to implement a button that activates a ForEach loop to go through each item in the list and mark it as delayed. This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AllJobsDelayWeather: View{
    var jobIndividualViewModel: JobIndividualViewModel
    @State public var comparisonDate = getCurrentDate()
    
    
    var body: some View{
        let jobDate = ParserDate(date: jobIndividualViewModel.job.date)
        Text(" ")
        if jobIndividualViewModel.job.completed == false && jobDate == comparisonDate{ //error is here
            jobIndividualViewModel.delayWeather(jobIndividualViewModel.job) 
               Text(" ")
            }
        Text(" ")
        
        }
}
```

This is in the "main" (if you can call it) portion of the program

```
Button("Delay Bad Weather"){
                    ForEach(jobViewModel.jobIndividualViewModels) { jobVM in
                        AllJobsDelayWeather(jobIndividualViewModel: jobVM)
                    }
                }.padding()
```

I am getting this error: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols. The function works and has been "ad hoc" tested. I don't know how to get rid of the error that the compiler is throwing.

***EDIT***
Currently trying to do this:

```
//in body
Button("Delay Bad Weather"){
                    ForEach(jobViewModel.jobIndividualViewModels) { jobVM 
//errors getting thrown above
                        AllJobDelayWeather(jobVM: jobVM)
                    }
                }.padding()

//outside if struct in the same file

func AllJobDelayWeather(jobVM: JobIndividualViewModel){
    let comparisonDate = getCurrentDate()
    
    let jobDate = ParserDate(date: jobVM.job.date)
    if jobVM.job.completed == false && jobDate == comparisonDate{
        jobVM.delayWeather(jobVM.job)

        }
    
}
```

I am now getting 2 instances of the error, one on the F of ForEach and the { before the first instance of jobVM.

Comment: There are a couple of forms of the `Button` initializer. With the one you're using, the trailing closure (what is in between in the `{ }`) is the *action* (ie what the action should do). You're trying to put a `View` inside the action. I'm not totally clear on what the desired outcome is here, though.

Comment: I'm just trying to make a function to change a field in job through the use of the delayWeather function. you can say it's an action, but I need to have it in a struct because if it is in the "main" program, I get errors with the compiler itself.

Comment: What is the button "Delay Bad Weather" supposed to do?

Comment: It is supposed to update all jobs of the day with a delay and add more time to an estimate.

Comment: You can't have any view stuff in `Button("LabelName") { no_views_in_here }`. I you want to add code, edit your original question -- as you found out, the comments don't format code well

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're using `ForEach`, which is a SwiftUI view, inside a Button's `action` closure, where you can't have views. Looking at your updated code, it looks like you just want a regular forEach. Something like:

```
Button("Delay Bad Weather") {
   jobViewModel.jobIndividualViewModels.forEach { jobVM
     allJobDelayWeather(jobVM: jobVM)
   }
}.padding()
```

```
func allJobDelayWeather(jobVM: JobIndividualViewModel){
    let comparisonDate = getCurrentDate()
    
    let jobDate = ParserDate(date: jobVM.job.date)
    if jobVM.job.completed == false && jobDate == comparisonDate{
        jobVM.delayWeather(jobVM.job)
    }
}
```

I changed your function name to lowercase because that's the preferred naming convention in Swift. It's also somewhat unusual to have a function floating outside of a view like you imply in your comments -- it probably belongs inside the view or inside the view model (hard to say since I can't see all of your code).

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I was on break and wasn't in front of a Mac, so I couldn't implement this till now.